How to parse AWS Amplify GraphQL String Query 'serializedData'
I'm using AWS Amplify with Flutter. In the Amplify generated model class, there is a fromJson() function like such:
  RoomWantedProfile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)  
    : id = json['id'],
      _moveInBy = json['moveInBy'],
      _whatsApp = json['whatsApp'],
      _description = json['description'],
      _user = json['user']?['serializedData'] != null
        ? User.fromJson(new Map<String, dynamic>.from(json['user']['serializedData']))
        : null;

I make a GraphQL request and the response is in string form so I parse the string using fromJson(). This successfully parses all the attributes such as 'moveInBy' and 'whatsApp', but 'user' is parsed as null. As you can see, it attempts to access this 'serializedData' member which doesn't actually exist in the recieved response which seems to be what is causing it to fail and then assign user as null.
I could just try to fix it by manually editing the fromJson() function to remove the [serializedData] part but ideally I want a solution that works with the generated code itself.
I also tried specifying modelType in the GraphQLRequest but that just recieved null.
Anyone know how to do so?
